# @property cgpoint not working

Tags: objective-c, properties

I've been banging my head around this for some time...
I have a an @property for a CGPoint in my ball class and I just can't assign it a new CGPoint
The class that contains it looks like this

```
@interface Ball : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGPoint position;

@end

@implementation Ball

@end
```

later when I try to change the position like this

```
Ball * myBall = [[Ball alloc] init];

CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(100.0,100.0); // some random values here

myBall.position = myPoint;

NSLog(@"%f,%f", myBall.position.x, myBall.position.y);
```

the values it outputs are still `0.0000, 0.0000`

Comment: What do you get if you log `myBall`?

Comment: I copied your code into a project and tested it on the simulator.  It works fine.  Post your real code.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In some cases CGFloat is actually a `double`. Trying to print it as a `float` could lead to the results you're seeing.</strike>

Another possibility is that `myBall` is `nil` for some reason, in which case you'll definitely get zeroes for its properties. That shouldn't be the case for the code you posted, but sometimes people (over)simplify when posting code.

Comment: `NSLog()` is variadic: its `float` arguments are implicitly promoted to `double` when passed, and if its implementation is correct, then `%f` is treated equivalently with `%lf` (not good style, but works.)

Comment: You're welcome. This is an important little detail (which isn't obvious). I've learnt this from a comment on SO too.

Comment: Sorry... I know that neither of those could be the issue. it also has an at property value of radius which is a CGFloat and it is working fine... I may just have to separate the x and y coordinates but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
CGPoint
```

are not Objective-c Objects, they are C Structs. Your property *position* is not an instance of an Object

Comment: A property can have a `struct` type.  For example, check out the `center` property of `UIView`.

Answer (score -2):

Try `@synthesize myPoint;` in your `Ball.m` class.

edit: Others have said this probably isn't the issue, apologies.

Comment: This is not relevant unless Matt is using a fairly old version of Xcode.

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary with recent compilers.

Comment: Ah okay, I've ran into similar problems so I thought that might be it.

Comment: It would crash anyway if compiled with older compilers.